# Best Practices: Standalone Components vs. Modules in Angular 14

Tags: angular, typescript, components, angular-module

I'm seeking clarification on the best practices regarding the usage of standalone components and modules in Angular 14. Given the introduction of standalone components as a new concept in Angular, I'm looking for factual guidance supported by citations or references.

I've created a new whole app only using standalone components with lazy loading routes, and everything works perfectly. Here the repo: https://github.com/Ismaestro/angular-example-app

However, I'm curious if this indicates a potential shift towards standalone components rendering NgModules obsolete.

Could someone provide evidence-based insights into the advantages and disadvantages of employing standalone components versus modules in Angular 14?

Thank you for your contributions.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Standalone components are not mandatory and will never be, there is no rule when to use them. However, Angular Architects recommend to always use Standalone components at least for new components you create. They are simply more treeshakeable and less boiler. You can mix standalone components and modules also.

For the mentioned recommendation of the Angular Architects, you can also watch the Webinar from last Monday: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9rj8kR0q0c8

Comment: Nice!, so I guess if I start a new application is better to use only standalone components? Thanks for the link

Comment: Yes, this approach is recommended. That is the way Angular is going forward.

Comment: I'm playing with standalone components right now and I agree that we should all use standalone components over modules (at least going forward). That said, I think a potentially valid reason to use a module would be if you _know for a fact_ that some number of components you are writing will _always_ be used _together_. Then I would still write them as standalone components, but you can easily create a module to import and export all of the components so they are easy to import as one unit. This is just and idea I'm playing with and would love to here other thoughts.

Comment: I think thats a fair use of ng modules!. I've created a post on dev.to and an example app. Here the links: https://dev.to/ismaestro/implementing-standalone-components-in-angular-15-3c2p and https://github.com/Ismaestro/angular-example-app

Comment: currently i use modules for the sake of grouping components and services for a specific functionality. 
for example i need something that is made up of 3 or more components and has some services that are suitable only for that single functionality , i group them in a single module . 
but for simple functionalities or the sake of sharing code and preventing unnecessary repeated code, standalone components are amazing! and they have no limitations, for your new projects you can only use standalone components with no problems

Comment: @PayamB.   Hi, is it possible to actually use a standalone component to do the grouping of components and services for a specific functionality, instead of using module.    If possible, wonder what is the advantage of using module over standalone in such case.

Comment: "Standalone components are not mandatory and will never be".   So does that mean module will NEVER be deprecated and removed in future? Cos if the day come when module is really removed, then standalone components will have to be mandatory.

Comment: That is what they said, there is no plan to remove modules.

Comment: So is there any, and I mean ANY reason to NOT to use standalone coponents, ever? Where would we declare root paths, or an NgRx root?

Comment: I total agree with @PayamB. NgModule and StandaloneComponent should used flexibal case by case.

Comment: We have a big project with loads of services, which are often shared across components, so we currently put the services in a module and load that module in the components that need it, so that (in theory) the service only gets provided once but it's not in the root of the application. I can't really find a good way to do this with standalone components. Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 3):

For practical upsides/downsides of using Standalone vs Modules check out this discussion on Reddit:
https://www.reddit.com/r/Angular2/comments/118i0pf/do_standalone_components_cause_duplicate_code_in/

The answer is not so easy and straightforward as some debaters suggest. I'm not going to repeat many advantages of standalone - they are stated everywhere, but the main omitted disadvantage of using only standalone components seems that you might end up loading the same code many times as described within the discussion. I will also borrow the conclusion from there:

"So I guess it becomes a balancing act of including too much in main.js vs having things duplicated in multiple lazy-loaded files? Like maybe if something's really needed everywhere, I would keep it in Shared but if it's only needed by some modules it might be better to make it standalone?" [R00B0T](https://www.reddit.com/user/R00B0T/)