# Should I update every component as standalone?

Tags: angular, angular15

I'm a bit confused with the latest Angular update concerning standalone components. I read they are more efficient, but does this imply that every component (mid-size project) should be migrated to being a standalone component?
While it may be more efficient, with e.g. lazy loading, I thought that you have to import way too many modules for each component. Even though Angular does this automatically when migrating, I am unsure about future additions to the code :/

Can someone explain if or why I should migrate my project fully to consist of standalone components?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend opting for standalone components and eliminating the ngModule structure. As outlined in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74558393/when-to-use-standalone-components-or-modules-in-angular-14), adopting standalone components can lead to a more optimised tree structure for your application.